# Yii2 сохранение сессии

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет!

Разрабатываю проект на yii2, возник вопрос:
пользователь авторизован на сайте, если закрыть окно браузера с активным личным кабинетом, а затем открыть заново то страница с профилем загрузится в полном обьеме, но стоит перейти допустим из профиля в другое место сайта, выскакивает сообщение, что вы не зарегистрированы. Вроде все как надо, вот только если бы при открытии не грузился личный кабинет, может кто то подскажет как быть?

Comment: Вполне вероятно, что страница загружается из кэша браузера. Если ее обновить, скорее всего она будет недоступна.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках приложения в компоненте user установите autoLogin => true.
Это включит режим аутентификации по кукам.
Личный кабинет отображается, потому что либо Вы не закрыли от анонимов эту страницу, либо срабатывает какой-то кэш